# file uplaod php maximum files

Tags: php, file-upload

i would like to upload some files with php.
i got the following warning:
Warning: Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0

But i can't find the maximum allowable files that can be uploaded.
Can i ignore the size or setting the size higher to upload all my files?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to show some code. How many files are you trying to upload? What PHP version is your server running? Is the Suhosin patch running?

Comment: **another duplicated question** http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20maximum%20file%20site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: i don't think that my questions needs to show some code.

Comment: have a foreach loop and a for loop. At the moment the user have the chance to upload 42 Files at the same time. This is not possible, because of my shown problem. I'm using php 5.3.1. What is the suhosing plugin?

Comment: [Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438551/608639), [file uplaod php maximum files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4144076/608639), [Maximum number of allowable, no max_file_uploads in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22882326/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are exceeding the PHP configured `max_file_uploads` variable. Which is set to a default of `50` (on Debian Lenny).

You can find and configure this variable in `php.ini`. <s>You can not set it in a .htaccess file or at runtime with ini_set() because of a bug: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50684&edit=1</s>

In `php.ini` there is:

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 50
```

Comment: I'm using xampp for orking with php on my machine and in the php.ini i didn't find the variable. now i put the variable manually under the upload section and i didn't work.

Comment: Now it is possible to set max_file_uploads through ini_set function. Anyway thanks as your answer led me in that direction and solved my problem.