# Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

We're uploading about 500 images at a time

```
max_file_uploads = 600
memory_limit = 200M ( most images are 12-15KB )
post_max_size = 200M
```

Why are we still getting that warning?

**EDIT**: All these variables are set in the php.ini file and confirmed by checking using phpinfo();

Comment: Are you sure to look at the right php.ini, the one that's listed in the output of `phpinfo()` when called through a web browser?

Comment: Does it appear in the *Local Value* or in the *Master Value* value column? Are you setting it somewhere else? Have you restarted Apache (if mod_php) or the PHP processes (if fastcgi)?

Comment: @rik: Yes, used `php -i | grep Configuration` to check the php.ini file I should be editing. @Alvaro: both the master and local values are same for all these variables.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: There might be different php.ini for mod_php and the CLI. You have to save `<?php phpinfo();` to a file in your document root and access it with your browser!

Comment: @rik: that's exactly what i did, i didn't run it as a CLI

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: You did. `php -i | grep` is definitely a shell command. Can you provide a link to your phpinfo script?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The PHP script won't even start executing until all the files have been uploaded. That means that you cannot change the `max_file_uploads` directive from within PHP, e.g. with `ini_set()`: you need to do it in the `php.ini` file. Otherwise, when you change the setting the limit has already been hit.

Comment: And even though that's a PHP error message, it bears pointing out that Apache can/will limit upload sizes via LimitRequestBody in httpd.conf

Comment: Also look to see if the `suhosin` php extension has been installed. It carries it's own upload limit: `suhosin.upload.max_uploads`. I found it by looking at the exact number of uploads that were successful (25 out of 120, in my case) and searching my `phpinfo()` for that number (25).

Comment: a little late on this, but do you believe it possible to add it to the htaccess `php_value max_file_uploads 1000` as I only want to to be accessible to a particular folder (more specifically and admin section) and not as a global param?

Comment: @SamuelCook - [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) say it's [PHP_INI_SYSTEM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Answer (score 18):

```
add max_file_uploads=500 to php.ini
```