# Can't post more than 8 pictures in a row

Tags: php, image, file, post

I'm trying to post many pictures at the same time. I tried changing `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`, but it didn't work; I could only post 8 pictures at a time.

```
post_max_size = 12MB
upload_max_filesize = 12MB
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code if you would like assistance with your problem.

Comment: Your question is confused, please add more details to be clearer, "post" you refer to the post method? what is the "row" for you? would Database?

Comment: The <input type='file'> only handles a single file at a time. You can get jQuery plugins (and other no jQuery libraries) to upload multiple files to your server.

Comment: How big is each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check also `max_file_uploads` setting in your **php.ini** file. Also notise, that you can't change this setting during runtime, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438551/maximum-number-of-allowable-file-uploads-has-been-exceeded).

Try next values:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
max_file_uploads = 10
```

And there is no shorthandbytes like **"MB"**. You should use **"K"**, **"M"**, **"G"** for that. Check [this FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes).

Comment: I changed the Parameters to upload_max_filesize = 10485760MB which equal to 10 méga and I discovered that my code can only upload 10 Mega per row and not 8 images,  How can i make the code upload 10 mega per FILE and not in the total

Comment: Your max post_max_size must have value <file_size>*<files_count>. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I don't have this Lane max_file_uploads  Where shall i add it plz, under uploa max file size no ?

Comment: Brother Thank you this is working this lane is the key max_file_uploads = 10 thanks <3

Comment: @user2303038 The default value of max_file_uploads is 20 btw, so I think the post_max_size change was the actual fix.