# How to set number of file upload in php

Tags: php

```
    ini_set('max_file_uploads', "50");
```

I have used it to set the number of files uploaded in my PHP file, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

As Álvaro G. Vicario states in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438551/maximum-number-of-allowable-file-uploads-has-been-exceeded/4438613#4438613):

> The PHP script won't even start executing until all the files have
>   been uploaded.
>
> **That means** that you cannot change the `max_file_uploads` directive from within PHP, e.g. with `ini_set()`: you need to do it in the
>   `php.ini` file.
>
> Otherwise, when you change the setting the limit has already been hit.

**EDITED**. in PHP.INI must be : `file_uploads = On`