# Maximum number of allowable, no max_file_uploads in php.ini

Tags: php, html, laravel, file-upload

I have a PHP which lets the user upload to a maximum of 20 files. When I submit the pictures I am getting the following error in the error_log =>  PHP Warning:  Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0

When I created a phpinfo file under max_file_uploads I have 20 under Local Value and Master Value 'Configuration PHP Core'.

When I open the php.ini file I cannot find the max_file_uploads and when I insert the 'max_file_uploads = 50' the value in my php info file (above) remains the same i.e. 20.

What am I doing wrong please?

**UPDATE**

I am on a shared host... I tried doing this ini_set('max_file_uploads', 50); but it didn't work.

The host told me that they cannot restart the server as 'on shared hosting, there is no way to reset/restart the server as that would effect hundreds of different accounts'

Comment: Make sure you're editing the correct php.ini file; make sure you restart your webserver afterwards; and perhaps your hosting provider doesn't allow that ini setting to be changed

Comment: @MarkBaker I am sure it is the correct file.

Comment: This is executed via HTTP; did you restart your web server after updating php.ini?

Comment: You using WAMP? If you are, the files get generated on the fly, not the ones that are in the actual directories. You need to go through the system tray icon and get to "Edit PHP.INI" via that way.

Comment: @Fluffeh I am using them on shared hosting

Comment: Have you tried throwing out a `phpinfo()` and seeing what the results are?

Comment: That is what I did.... See my question above, please. 'When I created a phpinfo file under max_file_uploads I have 20 under Local Value and Master Value 'Configuration PHP Core' and 'When I open the php.ini file I cannot find the max_file_uploads and when I insert the 'max_file_uploads = 50' the value in my php info file (above) remains the same i.e. 20.'

Comment: I updated my query as I am on shared hosting

Comment: [Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438551/608639), [file uplaod php maximum files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4144076/608639), [Maximum number of allowable, no max_file_uploads in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22882326/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Detailed Description](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/increase-upload-size-in-your-phpini#:%7E:text=The%20default%20values%20for%20PHP,post_max_size%27%20and%20%27upload_max_filesize%27.)

The default values for PHP will restrict you to a maximum 2 MB upload file size. On the settings page for the upload module, Drupal calculates and displays the maximum file size that you can set based upon two PHP settings: 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_filesize'.